# Why pointer to arr[i] cannot be assigned while pointer to arr+i can be assigned directly?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int n;
     printf("Enter number of elements you want in array:");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int arr[10],*a;
    //taking input from user
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",arr+i);
    }
   
    //stroing values in array and showing them on output screen
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
     a=&arr[i];
     printf("Element %d:",i);
     printf("%d\n",*(arr+i));
    }
    
 }
```

output:

```
Enter number of elements you want in array:4
Enter element 0: 5
Enter element 1: 6
Enter element 2: 7
Enter element 3: 8
Element 0:5
Element 1:6
Element 2:7
Element 3:8
```

The above code is easily showing output but the code pasted below is showing error

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int n;
     printf("Enter number of elements you want in array:");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int arr[10],*a;
    //taking input from user
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
   
    //stroing values in array and showing them on output screen
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
     a=&arr[i];
     printf("Element %d:",i);
     printf("%d\n",*(arr[i]));
    }
    
 }
```

Output:

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.c: In function 'main':
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:21:20: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
   21 |      printf("%d\n",*(arr[i]));
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
```

Why is it so what is wrong with this code and and why the code above is running successfully???

Comment: `arr[i]` isn't the same as `arr + i`.

Comment: `arr[i]` returns the contents of the array element, you don't need to use `*`.

Comment: `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr+i)`

Comment: `arr+i` is equivalent to `&arr[i]`

Comment: `*(arr[i])` says "dereference the address stored at `arr[i]`", however `arr[i]` is not a pointer, it's an integer.

Comment: `arr[i]` has type `'int`.  So `*arr[i]` is an attempt to use an integer as a pointer, which is meaningless in C.  Lose the `*`.

Comment: Does this question need the C++ tag? This looks like pure C code.

Comment: See also: "[Practical difference between using array and pointer offset notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58160944/90527)"

Comment: @Barmar `arr+i` is only equivalent to `&arr[i]` if `arr[i]` is in bounds. If it's the one-past-the-end pointer then the dereference is UB.

Comment: @Caleth `arr+i` doesn't dereference anything, only `*(arr+i)` does. Both forms are equivalent in their behavior definedness.

Comment: @Barmar `&arr[i]` is defined as `&*(arr+1)`, there is a dereference

Comment: @Caleth Can you cite the section of the spec?

Comment: "The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`" [`[expr.sub]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.sub#1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer points to an address in memory.

If you add an integer, you move the pointer:

```
int v = 10;
int *p = &v;
p = p + 3 // 3 addresses further. Which is currently nothing.
```

If you use the asterisk, you get the value at the particular address.

```
int v = 10;
int *p = &v;
*p == 10; // true
```

Using brackets is like both placing the pointer and dereferencing at the same time. `p[3]` is the same as `*(p+3)`

You already use brackets, which means you're trying to dereference an 'int' instead of an 'int pointer'