# what is the difference between *p and p[1]?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Here is a code for dynamic memory allocation using `malloc`

```c
void main()
{
    int *p,n=5;
    p=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));

    p[0]=10;
    //  or *p=10;
    p[1]=20
    //  or *(p+1)=20;
}
```

As per my knowledge, `p` is a pointer variable that points to the base address of the allocated memory. If I dont use the `*` operator, then I can't access the contents pointed to by `p`. But the statements `p[1]=20` and `*(p+1)=20`
do work the same. Why is this same and also what is the use of `*` if we can do it this way too `p[1]`
But then does it also means that when i use malloc the array allocated to the process will have the same name as the pointer used to point the base address

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Practical difference between using array and pointer offset notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160944/practical-difference-between-using-array-and-pointer-offset-notation)

Comment: it is hard to understand the question gven there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between *p and p[1] is that *p is a pointer that points to the first element of the array, while p[1] is the second element of the array. The difference is that *p gives you access to the entire array, while p[1] only gives you access to the single element.

Comment: No i mean difference between using *p=10 and p[0]=10  or *(p+1)=20 and p[1]=20

Comment: But then does it also means then when i use malloc the array allocated to the process will have the same name as the pointer used to point the base address

Comment: *p=10 and p[0]=10 is the same thing. It just looks different. When you use malloc you're allocating memory that can hold a set amount of things. It allocates an array, yes, but it's more like a block of memory starting at p. p is just the variable used to represent the base address.

Comment: they are the same p lol

Comment: One more thing ,does the name of an array represents the base address of the array and element array[2] as an example means 1000(assuming base address)+2*sizeof(data type)

Comment: A variable name is something you would use to represent some block of memory. For example int x = 4. x is used to represent the data at some memory location as an integer. The pointer or the base address of x is the location of that memory.  Your example with array[2] is correct!